# Touchable Opacity not working with iPhone 6,6s,8 but working with iPhone 11

Tags: ios, react-native, touchableopacity

I don't know why but I have this 1 touchable opacity tag that seems to work in iPhone 11 but does not work in iPhone 6s,6,8. Is there some difference in usage for different iPhones? This tag also works perfectly in android but doesn't seem to work in in older iPhones. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you. I have imported the touchable opacity from `react-native`.

Code.

```
<TouchableOpacity disabled={disabled} activeOpacity={opacity} style={buttonStyles} >
  {renderContent()}
</TouchableOpacity>
```

Answer (score 0):

It works but your `TouchableOpacity` is not inside the block of parent. Try to put your `TouchableOpacity` like this if you want test if works. **It's just a problem of Dimension**

```
     return (
        <View style={{ flex: 1, backgroundColor: 'red'  }}>
            <TouchableOpacity style={{ width: 150, height: 60, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' }}
             onPress={() => {alert("it's work")}}>
                <Text>Press Me</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
     )
```